# Invalid column name Discriminator

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

OK. I've been around the block a few times on this one. I had some classes that were inheriting from Entity Framework code-first classes that I have rewritten to eliminate the inheritance.

However, I'm getting this strange error when trying to read a table through Entity Framework that is NOT inherited, has a primary key defined in the table AND has that primary key identified in the cs code with the [key] tag.

Here's the cs Entity Framework code:

```
namespace Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    [Table("tblMember")]
    public partial class tblMember
    {
        [Key]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string CN { get; set; }

      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public int MemberUID { get; set; }

      [Required]
        [StringLength(1024)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [StringLength(25)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string firstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(25)]
        public string middleName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string lastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(400)]
        public string eMail { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(64)]
        public string GUID { get; set; }

        public bool eMail_verified { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
        public DateTime dtRegDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string orgName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string orgStreet1 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string orgStreet2 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string orgCity { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string orgProvince { get; set; }

        [StringLength(53)]
        public string orgCountry { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string orgPostal { get; set; }

        [StringLength(25)]
        public string HomeTelephone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(25)]
        public string WorkTelephone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string billName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string billStreet1 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string billStreet2 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string billCity { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string billProvince { get; set; }

        [StringLength(53)]
        public string billCountry { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string billPostal { get; set; }

        [StringLength(250)]
        public string pwdQuestion { get; set; }

        [StringLength(250)]
        public string pwdAnswer { get; set; }

        public bool canReview { get; set; }

        public bool IMV_Registered { get; set; }

        public int TimeZoneID { get; set; }

        public decimal TimeZoneOffset { get; set; }

        [StringLength(11)]
        public string tm_NPI_Number { get; set; }

        public bool tm_bHashedPassword { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        public string tm_PasswordSalt { get; set; }

        public int? tm_NPI_SourceID { get; set; }

        public virtual tblMemberNPI_Source tblMemberNPI_Source { get; set; }

   }
}
```

Here's the code trying to get a member out of the table:

```
               var objJunk = from mem in dbContext.tblMembers
                             where mem.MemberUID == objRpm.rcm_MemberUID
                             select mem;
               string strJunk = objJunk.ToString();
```

And here's the generated SQL (the value of strJunk):

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
    [Extent1].[CN] AS [CN], 
    [Extent1].[MemberUID] AS [MemberUID], 
    [Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Extent1].[firstName] AS [firstName], 
    [Extent1].[middleName] AS [middleName], 
    [Extent1].[lastName] AS [lastName], 
    [Extent1].[eMail] AS [eMail], 
    [Extent1].[GUID] AS [GUID], 
    [Extent1].[eMail_verified] AS [eMail_verified], 
    [Extent1].[dtRegDate] AS [dtRegDate], 
    [Extent1].[orgName] AS [orgName], 
    [Extent1].[orgStreet1] AS [orgStreet1], 
    [Extent1].[orgStreet2] AS [orgStreet2], 
    [Extent1].[orgCity] AS [orgCity], 
    [Extent1].[orgProvince] AS [orgProvince], 
    [Extent1].[orgCountry] AS [orgCountry], 
    [Extent1].[orgPostal] AS [orgPostal], 
    [Extent1].[HomeTelephone] AS [HomeTelephone], 
    [Extent1].[WorkTelephone] AS [WorkTelephone], 
    [Extent1].[billName] AS [billName], 
    [Extent1].[billStreet1] AS [billStreet1], 
    [Extent1].[billStreet2] AS [billStreet2], 
    [Extent1].[billCity] AS [billCity], 
    [Extent1].[billProvince] AS [billProvince], 
    [Extent1].[billCountry] AS [billCountry], 
    [Extent1].[billPostal] AS [billPostal], 
    [Extent1].[pwdQuestion] AS [pwdQuestion], 
    [Extent1].[pwdAnswer] AS [pwdAnswer], 
    [Extent1].[canReview] AS [canReview], 
    [Extent1].[IMV_Registered] AS [IMV_Registered], 
    [Extent1].[TimeZoneID] AS [TimeZoneID], 
    [Extent1].[TimeZoneOffset] AS [TimeZoneOffset], 
    [Extent1].[tm_NPI_Number] AS [tm_NPI_Number], 
    [Extent1].[tm_bHashedPassword] AS [tm_bHashedPassword], 
    [Extent1].[tm_PasswordSalt] AS [tm_PasswordSalt], 
    [Extent1].[tm_NPI_SourceID] AS [tm_NPI_SourceID], 
    [Extent1].[projectId] AS [projectId]
    FROM [dbo].[tblMember] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'newRybbonMember',N'tblMember')) AND ([Extent1].[MemberUID] = @p__linq__0)
```

Not sure where the hell it's getting newRybbonMember or projectId from since neither are in the tblMember definition.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.
TIA,

Comment: There's probably a partial part somewhere else.

Comment: Regrading discriminator. You seem to have a class `newRybbonMember` inheriting the `tblMember` inside the same project. EF6 has the bad habbit of automatically finding the derived classes inside the same project and including them in the model.

Comment: As for `projectId`, it could come from `project` class having `ICollection<tblMember>` property (or `ICollection<newRybbonMember>`)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Ivan Stoev hit the nail on the head! I finally found a class that inherited from tblMember way out in the woods of the code. Eliminated the inheritance and the issue went away! Thank you!